# How to get the title of a product (Woo-Commerce) to show up in white text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress, html, and all so I'm learning slowly but surely. Currently while working on a website for my business, the shop page has 6 items listed but none of the titles of the items are listed. Only the picture themselves. The background and text color of the titles are both #222222. I'm trying to change the text color of the title which is `h2`. The name of the header is `h2.woocommerce-loop-product_title` as seen in the inspector.

None of the code I've tried has worked so how would I properly reformat the text color?

http://middlesexworms.com/index.php/shop/

---

Code I've tried:

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6{
  font-family: 'Krub', sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: The code you have tried will override all the heading elements which is not what you would want :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit this class:

```
h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title, .woocommerce div.product .product_title {
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```

Old class is :

```
h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title, .woocommerce div.product .product_title {
    color: #0000;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```

So i change color from `#000000` to `#fffffff`

Comment: He might need to add `!important` based on different situations in WordPress. He can try adding a parent element `woocommerce-loop-product__link` to increase the specificity in that case. To override.

Comment: no need to add `!important`, I try in live wwebsite and work good

Answer (score 0):

You can change color by navigating to style.css file of the theme. I hope you can access that file through FTP client. Login to your server using FTP or cPanel go to your webiste setup root then /wp-content/themes/vw-gardening-landscaping/style.css. Go on line #1272 and change color property to #fff.

If you don't have access login to wp-admin navigate to appearance > editor. There you can see the sytle.css change the property on line #1272 to #fff

I know this is not standard practice to edit theme's core file but if you couldn't [enqueue your own stylesheet](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) or not created [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) you have to do this.

You can enqueue your own stylesheet setting dependency as theme's style.css and over write the rules as

```
h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title, .woocommerce div.product .product_title {
color: #fff !important; }
```

Let me know if you wish further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Before I saw your answers, i did a ton of googling. Seems as though there are a lot of ways to fix it but this one was what I used:

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6{
  font-family: 'Krub', sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}


h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title, .woocommerce div.product .product_title {
  color:#FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  margin-bottom:10px !important;
}
```